# MacBook stuck on login screen but accessible via TeamViewer

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mojave, login

Wondering if anyone can shed some light on this issue.

I have an early 2013 macbook pro, running osx mojave. The battery was shot and would shut off randomly so I had to take the power adapter with me all the time. So I replaced the battery, which all went fine except now when I power up the laptop and log in I get a progress bar that moves to about two thirds and then stops.

But, it also appears in my list of computers in Teamviewer and if I connect to it and I can use it as normal because it bypasses the login screen for some reason.

**Any suggestions how I get the laptop to get past the login screen?**

I have tried...

- resetting PRAM, NVRAM, and SMC
- Restoring from timemachine backup, this started but wouldn't
  finish and got stuck on black screen with apple logo
- Re-installing osx from osx - again got stuck on the black screen
- Re-installing from a usb boot disk image and same as above
- Re-installing using the web installer and same as above
- Also tried starting in safe mode and couldn't get passed login

Thanks in advance

Rob

Comment: Hi Rob - is it possible TeamViewer has locked the local screen and you need to uninstall or configure that app?

Comment: It's a good thought, but this issue happens before I connect with teamviewer. I double checked the Teamviewer settings just to be sure and there is nothing in there that says lock the screen. Thanks

Comment: So what exact version and type of TeamViewer is installed - some like the host app start at boot, doesn’t matter if you have logged in and it’s running already.

Comment: Out of left field - I wonder what would happen if via TeamViewer you could get into System Prefs/Users & Groups/Login Options & set it to auto-login to your main user? Perhaps also check Login Items & try disabling anything that could be blocking it.

Comment: @bmike it’s version 15.4.4445 

Comment: @Tetsujin I can’t use auto login as there is another user account .  I Did already disable all the startup apps but it had no effect.